# Oracle 10g connection with Java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

what are the drivers which are used to connect with java for Desktop application. i have found many types like tiny and all but was not able to understand. 
Please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your life easier, I would recommend just using Oracle's Thin Driver.

First, download the driver from [Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html):

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html
```

Then add JAR to your project and connect to database using:

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl", "scott", "tiger");
```

Of course, replace these parameters with the ones corresponding to your DB.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [official site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

**See Also**

- [JDBC kick start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

for oracle 10g the JDBC driver is "ojdbc10_g.jar"

it is available on your system inside %ORACLE_HOME\jdbc\lib
No need to download.

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection         ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl", "scott", "tiger"); 

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "thin" driver is a 100% java implementation. The OCI calls the C implementation. There might even be a JDBC to ODBC bridge, allowing you to use your system's ODBC driver. Suggested reading: [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one to deploy is probably the type 4 driver, or the thin driver.  I say it is the easiest because it does not rely on any Oracle native libraries or client install to operate.  It is readily available from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html).